# cabal-install-0.10.2 failed during the building phase

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, haskeline

I was trying to install haskeline, it's my first time installing using cabal, and here is what I got. What should I do?

```
. sudo cabal install haskeline
Password:
Config file /Users/arie/.cabal/config not found.
Writing default configuration to /Users/arie/.cabal/config
Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' does not exist. Run 'cabal
update' to download it.
cabal: There is no package named haskeline
. sudo cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Note: there is a new version of cabal-install available.
To upgrade, run: cabal install cabal-install
. sudo cabal install cabal-install
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading Cabal-1.10.2.0...
[ 1 of 61] Compiling Distribution.TestSuite ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/TestSuite.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/TestSuite.o )
[ 2 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Exception ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Compat/Exception.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Compat/Exception.o )
[ 3 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Compat.TempFile ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Compat/TempFile.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Compat/TempFile.o )
[ 4 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Compat.CopyFile ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Compat/CopyFile.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Compat/CopyFile.o )
[ 5 of 61] Compiling Distribution.GetOpt ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/GetOpt.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/GetOpt.o )
[ 6 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Compat.ReadP ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Compat/ReadP.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Compat/ReadP.o )
[ 7 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Text ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Text.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Text.o )
[ 8 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Version ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Version.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Version.o )
[ 9 of 61] Compiling Language.Haskell.Extension ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Language/Haskell/Extension.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Language/Haskell/Extension.o )
[10 of 61] Compiling Distribution.System ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/System.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/System.o )
[11 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.PreProcess.Unlit ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/PreProcess/Unlit.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/PreProcess/Unlit.o )
[12 of 61] Compiling Distribution.ReadE ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/ReadE.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/ReadE.o )
[13 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Verbosity ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Verbosity.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Verbosity.o )
[14 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Package ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Package.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Package.o )
[15 of 61] Compiling Distribution.ModuleName ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/ModuleName.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/ModuleName.o )
[16 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Utils ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Utils.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Utils.o )
[17 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Program.Types ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Program/Types.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Program/Types.o )
[18 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Program.Builtin ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Program/Builtin.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Program/Builtin.o )
[19 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Program.Db ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Program/Db.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Program/Db.o )
[20 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Program.Run ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Program/Run.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Program/Run.o )
[21 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Program ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Program.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Program.o )
[22 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Program.Ar ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Program/Ar.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Program/Ar.o )
[23 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Program.Ld ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Program/Ld.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Program/Ld.o )
[24 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Program.Script ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Program/Script.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Program/Script.o )
[25 of 61] Compiling Distribution.License ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/License.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/License.o )
[26 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Compiler ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Compiler.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Compiler.o )
[27 of 61] Compiling Distribution.PackageDescription ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/PackageDescription.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/PackageDescription.o )
[28 of 61] Compiling Distribution.PackageDescription.Configuration ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/PackageDescription/Configuration.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/PackageDescription/Configuration.o )
[29 of 61] Compiling Distribution.PackageDescription.Check ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/PackageDescription/Check.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/PackageDescription/Check.o )
[30 of 61] Compiling Distribution.ParseUtils ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/ParseUtils.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/ParseUtils.o )
[31 of 61] Compiling Distribution.InstalledPackageInfo ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/InstalledPackageInfo.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/InstalledPackageInfo.o )
[32 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.PackageIndex ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/PackageIndex.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/PackageIndex.o )
[33 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.GHC.IPI642 ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/GHC/IPI642.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/GHC/IPI642.o )
[34 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.GHC.IPI641 ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/GHC/IPI641.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/GHC/IPI641.o )
[35 of 61] Compiling Distribution.PackageDescription.Parse ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/PackageDescription/Parse.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/PackageDescription/Parse.o )
[36 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Command ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Command.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Command.o )
[37 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Compiler ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Compiler.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Compiler.o )
[38 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Program.HcPkg ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Program/HcPkg.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Program/HcPkg.o )
[39 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.InstallDirs ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/InstallDirs.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/InstallDirs.o )
[40 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Setup ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Setup.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Setup.o )
[41 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.LocalBuildInfo ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/LocalBuildInfo.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/LocalBuildInfo.o )
[42 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Build.Macros ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Build/Macros.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Build/Macros.o )
[43 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.BuildPaths ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/BuildPaths.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/BuildPaths.o )
[44 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Build.PathsModule ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Build/PathsModule.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Build/PathsModule.o )
[45 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.GHC ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/GHC.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/GHC.o )
[46 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.LHC ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/LHC.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/LHC.o )
[47 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.JHC ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/JHC.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/JHC.o )
[48 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.NHC ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/NHC.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/NHC.o )
[49 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.UHC ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/UHC.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/UHC.o )
[50 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Test ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Test.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Test.o )
[51 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.PreProcess ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/PreProcess.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/PreProcess.o )
[52 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Hugs ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Hugs.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Hugs.o )
[53 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Configure ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Configure.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Configure.o )
[54 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Install ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Install.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Install.o )
[55 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Register ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Register.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Register.o )
[56 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Build ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Build.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Build.o )
[57 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Haddock ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/Haddock.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/Haddock.o )
[58 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.SrcDist ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/SrcDist.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/SrcDist.o )
[59 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple.UserHooks ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple/UserHooks.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/UserHooks.o )
[60 of 61] Compiling Distribution.Simple ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Distribution/Simple.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple.o )
[61 of 61] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/Setup.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /tmp/Cabal-1.10.2.07503/Cabal-1.10.2.0/dist/setup/setup ...
Configuring Cabal-1.10.2.0...
Preprocessing library Cabal-1.10.2.0...
Building Cabal-1.10.2.0...
[ 1 of 62] Compiling Paths_Cabal      ( dist/build/autogen/Paths_Cabal.hs, dist/build/Paths_Cabal.o )
[ 2 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Exception ( Distribution/Compat/Exception.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Compat/Exception.o )
[ 3 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Compat.TempFile ( Distribution/Compat/TempFile.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Compat/TempFile.o )
[ 4 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Compat.CopyFile ( Distribution/Compat/CopyFile.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Compat/CopyFile.o )
[ 5 of 62] Compiling Distribution.GetOpt ( Distribution/GetOpt.hs, dist/build/Distribution/GetOpt.o )
[ 6 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Compat.ReadP ( Distribution/Compat/ReadP.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Compat/ReadP.o )
[ 7 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Text ( Distribution/Text.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Text.o )
[ 8 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Version ( Distribution/Version.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Version.o )
[ 9 of 62] Compiling Language.Haskell.Extension ( Language/Haskell/Extension.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Extension.o )
[10 of 62] Compiling Distribution.TestSuite ( Distribution/TestSuite.hs, dist/build/Distribution/TestSuite.o )
[11 of 62] Compiling Distribution.System ( Distribution/System.hs, dist/build/Distribution/System.o )
[12 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.PreProcess.Unlit ( Distribution/Simple/PreProcess/Unlit.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/PreProcess/Unlit.o )
[13 of 62] Compiling Distribution.ReadE ( Distribution/ReadE.hs, dist/build/Distribution/ReadE.o )
[14 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Verbosity ( Distribution/Verbosity.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Verbosity.o )
[15 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Package ( Distribution/Package.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Package.o )
[16 of 62] Compiling Distribution.ModuleName ( Distribution/ModuleName.hs, dist/build/Distribution/ModuleName.o )
[17 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Utils ( Distribution/Simple/Utils.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Utils.o )
[18 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Program.Types ( Distribution/Simple/Program/Types.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Program/Types.o )
[19 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Program.Builtin ( Distribution/Simple/Program/Builtin.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Program/Builtin.o )
[20 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Program.Db ( Distribution/Simple/Program/Db.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Program/Db.o )
[21 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Program.Run ( Distribution/Simple/Program/Run.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Program/Run.o )
[22 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Program ( Distribution/Simple/Program.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Program.o )
[23 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Program.Ar ( Distribution/Simple/Program/Ar.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Program/Ar.o )
[24 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Program.Ld ( Distribution/Simple/Program/Ld.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Program/Ld.o )
[25 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Program.Script ( Distribution/Simple/Program/Script.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Program/Script.o )
[26 of 62] Compiling Distribution.License ( Distribution/License.hs, dist/build/Distribution/License.o )
[27 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Compiler ( Distribution/Compiler.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Compiler.o )
[28 of 62] Compiling Distribution.PackageDescription ( Distribution/PackageDescription.hs, dist/build/Distribution/PackageDescription.o )
[29 of 62] Compiling Distribution.PackageDescription.Configuration ( Distribution/PackageDescription/Configuration.hs, dist/build/Distribution/PackageDescription/Configuration.o )
[30 of 62] Compiling Distribution.PackageDescription.Check ( Distribution/PackageDescription/Check.hs, dist/build/Distribution/PackageDescription/Check.o )
[31 of 62] Compiling Distribution.ParseUtils ( Distribution/ParseUtils.hs, dist/build/Distribution/ParseUtils.o )
[32 of 62] Compiling Distribution.InstalledPackageInfo ( Distribution/InstalledPackageInfo.hs, dist/build/Distribution/InstalledPackageInfo.o )
[33 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.PackageIndex ( Distribution/Simple/PackageIndex.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/PackageIndex.o )
[34 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.GHC.IPI642 ( Distribution/Simple/GHC/IPI642.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/GHC/IPI642.o )
[35 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.GHC.IPI641 ( Distribution/Simple/GHC/IPI641.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/GHC/IPI641.o )
[36 of 62] Compiling Distribution.PackageDescription.Parse ( Distribution/PackageDescription/Parse.hs, dist/build/Distribution/PackageDescription/Parse.o )
[37 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Command ( Distribution/Simple/Command.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Command.o )
[38 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Compiler ( Distribution/Simple/Compiler.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Compiler.o )
[39 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Program.HcPkg ( Distribution/Simple/Program/HcPkg.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Program/HcPkg.o )
[40 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.InstallDirs ( Distribution/Simple/InstallDirs.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/InstallDirs.o )
[41 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Setup ( Distribution/Simple/Setup.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Setup.o )
[42 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Make ( Distribution/Make.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Make.o )
[43 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.LocalBuildInfo ( Distribution/Simple/LocalBuildInfo.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/LocalBuildInfo.o )
[44 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Build.Macros ( Distribution/Simple/Build/Macros.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Build/Macros.o )
[45 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.BuildPaths ( Distribution/Simple/BuildPaths.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/BuildPaths.o )
[46 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Build.PathsModule ( Distribution/Simple/Build/PathsModule.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Build/PathsModule.o )
[47 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.GHC ( Distribution/Simple/GHC.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/GHC.o )
[48 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.LHC ( Distribution/Simple/LHC.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/LHC.o )
[49 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.JHC ( Distribution/Simple/JHC.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/JHC.o )
[50 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.NHC ( Distribution/Simple/NHC.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/NHC.o )
[51 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.UHC ( Distribution/Simple/UHC.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/UHC.o )
[52 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Test ( Distribution/Simple/Test.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Test.o )
[53 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.PreProcess ( Distribution/Simple/PreProcess.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/PreProcess.o )
[54 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Hugs ( Distribution/Simple/Hugs.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Hugs.o )
[55 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Configure ( Distribution/Simple/Configure.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Configure.o )
[56 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Install ( Distribution/Simple/Install.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Install.o )
[57 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Register ( Distribution/Simple/Register.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Register.o )
[58 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Build ( Distribution/Simple/Build.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Build.o )
[59 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Haddock ( Distribution/Simple/Haddock.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/Haddock.o )
[60 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.SrcDist ( Distribution/Simple/SrcDist.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/SrcDist.o )
[61 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple.UserHooks ( Distribution/Simple/UserHooks.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/UserHooks.o )
[62 of 62] Compiling Distribution.Simple ( Distribution/Simple.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple.o )
Registering Cabal-1.10.2.0...
Installing library in /Users/arie/.cabal/lib/Cabal-1.10.2.0/ghc-6.10.4
Registering Cabal-1.10.2.0...
Downloading HTTP-4000.0.6...
Configuring HTTP-4000.0.6...
Preprocessing library HTTP-4000.0.6...
Building HTTP-4000.0.6...
[ 1 of 15] Compiling Network.HTTP.Utils ( Network/HTTP/Utils.hs, dist/build/Network/HTTP/Utils.o )
[ 2 of 15] Compiling Network.HTTP.MD5Aux ( Network/HTTP/MD5Aux.hs, dist/build/Network/HTTP/MD5Aux.o )
[ 3 of 15] Compiling Network.HTTP.MD5 ( Network/HTTP/MD5.hs, dist/build/Network/HTTP/MD5.o )
[ 4 of 15] Compiling Network.HTTP.Base64 ( Network/HTTP/Base64.hs, dist/build/Network/HTTP/Base64.o )

Network/HTTP/Base64.hs:184:0:
    Warning: Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
             In the definition of `int4_char3': Patterns not matched: [_]

Network/HTTP/Base64.hs:242:0:
    Warning: Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
             In the definition of `quadruplets': Patterns not matched: [_]
[ 5 of 15] Compiling Network.Stream   ( Network/Stream.hs, dist/build/Network/Stream.o )
[ 6 of 15] Compiling Network.HTTP.Headers ( Network/HTTP/Headers.hs, dist/build/Network/HTTP/Headers.o )
[ 7 of 15] Compiling Network.BufferType ( Network/BufferType.hs, dist/build/Network/BufferType.o )
[ 8 of 15] Compiling Network.HTTP.Base ( Network/HTTP/Base.hs, dist/build/Network/HTTP/Base.o )
[ 9 of 15] Compiling Network.StreamSocket ( Network/StreamSocket.hs, dist/build/Network/StreamSocket.o )

Network/StreamSocket.hs:54:9:
    Warning: orphan instance: instance Stream Socket
[10 of 15] Compiling Network.TCP      ( Network/TCP.hs, dist/build/Network/TCP.o )
[11 of 15] Compiling Network.StreamDebugger ( Network/StreamDebugger.hs, dist/build/Network/StreamDebugger.o )
[12 of 15] Compiling Network.HTTP.Stream ( Network/HTTP/Stream.hs, dist/build/Network/HTTP/Stream.o )
[13 of 15] Compiling Network.HTTP.HandleStream ( Network/HTTP/HandleStream.hs, dist/build/Network/HTTP/HandleStream.o )
[14 of 15] Compiling Network.HTTP     ( Network/HTTP.hs, dist/build/Network/HTTP.o )
[15 of 15] Compiling Network.Browser  ( Network/Browser.hs, dist/build/Network/Browser.o )

Network/Browser.hs:1167:13: Warning: Defined but not used: `e'
ar: creating archive dist/build/libHSHTTP-4000.0.6.a
Installing library in /Users/arie/.cabal/lib/HTTP-4000.0.6/ghc-6.10.4
Registering HTTP-4000.0.6...
Reading package info from "dist/installed-pkg-config" ... done.
Writing new package config file... done.
Downloading cabal-install-0.10.2...
Configuring cabal-install-0.10.2...
Preprocessing executables for cabal-install-0.10.2...
Building cabal-install-0.10.2...
[ 1 of 44] Compiling Distribution.Client.Check ( Distribution/Client/Check.hs, dist/build/cabal/cabal-tmp/Distribution/Client/Check.o )
[ 2 of 44] Compiling Distribution.Client.PackageUtils ( Distribution/Client/PackageUtils.hs, dist/build/cabal/cabal-tmp/Distribution/Client/PackageUtils.o )
[ 3 of 44] Compiling Distribution.Client.Utils ( Distribution/Client/Utils.hs, dist/build/cabal/cabal-tmp/Distribution/Client/Utils.o )
[ 4 of 44] Compiling Distribution.Client.World ( Distribution/Client/World.hs, dist/build/cabal/cabal-tmp/Distribution/Client/World.o )
[ 5 of 44] Compiling Distribution.Client.BuildReports.Types ( Distribution/Client/BuildReports/Types.hs, dist/build/cabal/cabal-tmp/Distribution/Client/BuildReports/Types.o )
[ 6 of 44] Compiling Distribution.Compat.FilePerms ( Distribution/Compat/FilePerms.hs, dist/build/cabal/cabal-tmp/Distribution/Compat/FilePerms.o )

Distribution/Compat/FilePerms.hs:33:4:
    Not in scope: `throwErrnoPathIfMinus1_'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cabal-install-0.10.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
exit: ExitFailure 1
.
```

My spec (Let me know if you need more):

```
. ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 6.10.4
. which ghc
/opt/local/bin/ghc
. cabal --version
cabal-install version 0.6.2
using version 1.6.0.3 of the Cabal library 
. which cabal
/opt/local/bin/cabal
```

on Mac OS X 10.5.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised you got that far; in my experience `cabal-install` 1.10.x refuses to build (cabal throws an unsatisfied dependency) if `Cabal` (the low level library which is bundled with the compiler) is older than 1.10 (you have 1.6.0.3, like most of us using MacPorts `ghc`).  Aside: I'm rather annoyed that the MacPorts Haskell Platform is de facto a dead package; I ditched it and installed the official package.

Comment: cabal-install 0.10.x, not 1.10.x :)

Comment: @geekosaur, thanks for your reply. I'll consider having the official package once I got Lion on my MBP, hopefully it'll be smooth for not requiring too many dependencies like when I installed haskell from port.